# Why would MySQL change the type of join on a query in different databases

Tags: mysql

We have different RDS' (AWS, GCP etc..), and those RDS have many DBs. Each of our DBs is built and managed by the same backend code and thus all tables and datasets match across.

I have a query that when I run on one DB specifically it grinds to a halt, and comparing the explain shows it's being treated differently.

So for this example, I have first_table, and this FK's to second_table. All indexs etc.. are correctly formed.
And now lets say I have db_one on our AWS RDS, and we db_two,and db_three on our GCP database server.

first_table on db_one is 2gb, db_two it is 8.8gb, db_three it is 20mb.
second_table that we're FK-ing to is only 64kb.

```
select * from first_table a
where first_table a.my_date between '2020-12-01 00:00:00' and '2020-12-01 00:00:00';
```

If I run this on each db, the query takes under a second to run and return. On db_two, due to the size, it takes a few extra seconds to transfer the data over network to me - that's fine and expected.

When I run the `explain` on this it says "type: range, table: a". This is consistent across all the dbs.

Now when I add the FK join, and run on db_one. It's just as instant.

```
select * from first_table a
join second_table b on b.ft_id = a.id
where first_table a.my_date between '2020-12-01 00:00:00' and '2020-12-01 00:00:00';
```

However, when I run this on db_two (the biggest) it never finishes.
Now when I run the explain on both DBs, they are **different**.

On db_one it still uses "type: range, table: a" and "type: eq_ref, table: b"

On db_two it now says: "table: b, type: ALL, table: a, type: ref"

So I thought maybe there was a difference between these RDS, or something, so I ran the query and explain on db_three (which is on same server as db_two), it ran instantly and the explain was the same as on db_one.
Infact I ran the explain on all our RDS' on different databases, and it was always how I'd expect it: "table: a, type: range. table:b, type: eq_ref".

Only on db_two, with the biggest table, does the explain differ but also produce very very poor performance.

Can anyone help explain why this is happening? Or what is causing this, and can I get around it?

My current soluation is just to run the fast single table sql, and return to python, then pull the FK data, and manually stitch and sort it myself. At least that would run.
But that seems crazy.

Hopefully I'm miss understanding something here.

Comment: Execution plan is built each time you execute the query. The base for this is table statistic. If it is too old and/or is not accurate then wrong execution plan may be built. You may: renew statistic, force some index, add straight_join...

Comment: renew statistic: I tried ANALYZE TABLE and that didnt help. "straight_join" worked! I've never heard of this before. But forcing to "read left table first" is massive.
Thank you